# Why XSLT lookahead pattern is not worked in Saxon-HE 9.4 java

Tags: xslt, saxon

Construction for remove leading zeroes worked fine in Altova XML Spy.
With Saxon-HE 9.4 java got exception:

> Error at xsl:value-of on line 6 column 59 of question.xslt:
>    FORX0002: Error at character 4 in regular expression "^0+(?!$)": expected ())

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace('00012','^0+(?!$)','')"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have workaround, question is theoretical.
Maybe, special characters have to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saxon adheres rigidly to the syntax of regular expressions defined in the XPath specification. Some other engines may be more liberal, and allow whatever is permitted by the regular expression library they happen to be using. The syntax (?!$) is not allowed in the XPath spec.

In Perl, (?!$) is a zero-width negative lookahead assertion that matches everything except the end of the string. I guess that's the meaning you had in mind. So

```
replace('00012','^0+(?!$)','')
```

would remove any sequence of zeros at the start of the string provided it's not also at the end of the string. For example, it would would change 0012 to 12 while leaving 000 as 000. That seems a slighly strange requirement: normally I would just use string(xs:integer(.)) to remove all insignificant zeros, but this doesn't have the property of leaving '000' intact. If that's really what you need to do, then perhaps appending a 'Z' at the end of the string and then doing replace($x, '^0+[^Z]', '') would meet the need.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Such patten worked in Java. I hoped, if Saxon used Java "java.util.regex.Pattern" class for evaluate, it must work.
But now clear that all worked exaclty as mentioned in XPath specification.
Mentioned in question pattern just a lookahead sample.
Some notes about sample below.
Pattern remove leading zeroes, convert "0012 to "12" and "000" to "0".
Processed node have "xs:string" type, and for empty strings expression "string(xs:integer(.))" cause error. If add "0" to the begining of string, all have to work fine.
I used other workaround, provided pattern is not a issue.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of regular expressions in XSLT/XPath 2.0 is given in http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax and http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs. I don't think `(?!$)` is allowed in there.

Comment: Maybe, special characters have to be used instead of "?"? 
Also in XML Spy works fine.